# problem in declaring enum

Tags: java, enums

```
public enum ItemType{REFRENCE,ISSUE};
    ItemType itemType =  IntemType.ISSUE ;
    int intemNo=0;
```

I am geting error wheni use above code?why is it so?

Comment: What exactly is the error you get?

Comment: @Peter ItemType itemType =  IntemType.ISSUE ;

What is ItemType?

Comment: As far as i can see, it is a typo. That would give you a compilation error. Every IDE would warn you about it.

Comment: @Marius, why do you ask me? :-)

Comment: i have edited the code as it had spelling mistake

Comment: @akshay could you paste the error the compiler throws when you try to compile this? It will allow us to figure out the problem.

Comment: @akshay, it still has a spelling mistake...

Comment: @all:sorry all.There was a spelling mistake

Comment: @akshay, there still _is_ a spelling mistake, in row 2 of your code.

Comment: @akshay - please tell at least if it's runtime or a compile error and **which line** produces the error.

Comment: @all.The error was due to spelling mistake. thanks all

Comment: @Peter :) I see now that stupid old me thought you're actually asking about the error in the snippet. I stand rebuked!

Answer (score 3):

1. The code you provided (still) contains a typo: it's either `IntemType` or `ItemType`
2. Make sure, you use Java 1.5 or later. Earlier versions of Java do not support enums
3. Make sure, you compile with source level 1.6. It's one of my favourite mistakes in eclipse to use a Java 6 SDK and have a project configured for source level 1.4 ...
4. <strike>Your declaring an **interface** - an interface can't have fields. Declare it as a **class**</strike>
5. If none of the above helps - please edit your question and add error details.

---

Thanks for the comment, from JLS

> Every field declaration in the body of an interface is implicitly public, static, and final.

Comment: You cant declare a public enum and a public class/interface in the same file.  (Is that correct?)

Comment: Also, the enum declaration shouldn't end wit ha semicolon.

Comment: (I would edit your answer myself, but I'm not 100% sure about those.

Comment: An interface can have fields, they're just final by default. The enum is fine in there, too, though unnecessary.

Comment: am using java version "1.6.0_11"

Comment: Actually they're necessarily final, not just by default. You guys don't remember the bad old days when people used interfaces to emulate singletons?

Comment: @Justin, you can only have one _top level_ public class in the same file, but it may contain as many public inner classes / enums as you wish (well, up to a technical limit, which might be 255). And the semicolon is unnecessary, but is hardly an error.

Comment: @Justin - it's obsolete anyway after the last edits of the question ;)

Answer (score 0):

Did you compile with setting "source java 1.5"?
The enum syntax was't supported before java 1.5.

Comment: when i type java verion at command promt i get the following: java version "1.6.0_11"
Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 1.6.0_11-b03)
Java HotSpot(TM) Client VM (build 11.0-b16, mixed mode, sharing)